# Passing data from a UITableView cell to another VC's UITableView? (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, swift

I'm basically trying to pass data from a UITableView's cell, from one viewcontroller to my second viewcontroller when deleting a cell from the first viewcontroller.

Here's the code for my first viewcontroller class trying to pass the tableview data to an Array in my other viewcontroller class:

```
var deletedProperty: [String] = []
var storedDeletion: [String] = []

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){
        storedDeletion.append(deletedProperty[indexPath.row])
        taskMgr.tasks.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tblTasks.reloadData();
    }

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourIdentifier" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as ThirdViewController; destination.secondTaskMgr = storedDeletion
    }
}
```

Here's the code for my other viewcontroller class containing the Array:

```
var secondTaskMgr: SecondTaskManager = SecondTaskManager()

struct secondTask {
    var passedName = ""
}

class SecondTaskManager: NSObject {
    var secondTasks = [secondTask]()

    func secondAddTask(name: String){
        secondTasks.append(secondTask(passedName: name))
    }
}
```

In the first viewcontroller class I get the error

```
'NSArray' is not a subtype of 'ThirdViewController.SecondTaskManager'"
```

at

```
let destination = segue.destinationViewController as ThirdViewController;    
destination.secondTaskMgr = storedDeletion
```

What's the issue here and how do I fix it? And is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`secondTaskMgr` is a `SecondTaskManager`.

`storedDeletion` is a `[String]`.

You're trying to assign a `[String]` to a `SecondTaskManager` property.

You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSUserDefaults`.

FirstViewController.swift

```
let param: String = "ParamOne"
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(param, forKey:"paramId")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

SecondViewController.swift

```
let param = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("paramId")
```